# Creating simple tiny ELF from scratch

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, executable, elf

I am currently trying to create simple ELF executable using ELFIO library based on their docs (page 8) [1]. This is output from `readelf` when run on the slightly modified version of their code (nothing important, just different string and address base. Alignments, flags etc. are untouched.)

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - GNU
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x400000
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          4168 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         2
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         4
  Section header string table index: 1

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 00102e 000017 00      0   0  0
  [ 2] .text             PROGBITS        00400000 001000 00001d 00  AX  0   0 16
  [ 3] .data             PROGBITS        00400020 001020 00000e 00  WA  0   0  4
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)

There are no section groups in this file.

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x001000 0x00400000 0x00400000 0x0001d 0x0001d R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x001020 0x00400020 0x00400020 0x0000e 0x0000e RW  0x10

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .text 
   01     .data
```

This executable file runs fine. I wanted to move data section a little bit further from text section, so I have chosen address `0x400040`. here you can see that it is all I did.

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - GNU
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x400000
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          4168 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         2
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         4
  Section header string table index: 1

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 00102e 000017 00      0   0  0
  [ 2] .text             PROGBITS        00400000 001000 00001d 00  AX  0   0 16
  [ 3] .data             PROGBITS        00400040 001020 00000e 00  WA  0   0  4
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)

There are no section groups in this file.

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x001000 0x00400000 0x00400000 0x0001d 0x0001d R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x001020 0x00400040 0x00400040 0x0000e 0x0000e RW  0x10

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .text 
   01     .data
```

However, this file keeps seg. faulting on its start. I can't really understand what is going on. At first I though it has something to do with alignment of sections and segments but they seem OK to me. I have also suspected ASLR (because the address of Hello World is hardcoded and there are no relocations) and tried to turned it off in `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`. I have also checked linux kernel source code, especially file `fs/binfmt_elf.c`, but to fully understand what is going on there I will need more time. So I would like to ask for your help. If you know what is wrong with the address `0x400040`, why this file keeps seg. faulting, or you can point me to a certain lines of code in kernel, then I would really appreciate that.

Edit: I have also tried `gdb` but `bt` provides `No stack`. Setting read watchpoint on entry point address does not do anything.

Edit 2: After playing around with the file I found out that moving the file offset of second segment from `0x1020` to `0x1040` causes the file to work fine. So now my question is, does file offset and virtual address need to be in some relation?

[1] http://elfio.sourceforge.net/elfio.pdf

Comment: Have you tried loading it in `gdb`?  If there is a load failure, it will give a helpful error message.  If not, you should be able to single step and find out what goes wrong.

Comment: Take a look at [**The Teensy Files**](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/) which steps through some of what can be relocated within the ELF file while still resulting in a working executable.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have tried to. Edited the original post. Maybe I am just not using `gdb` properly.

Comment: Thanks David. I will read through that.

Answer (score 2):

> So now my question is, does file offset and virtual address need to be in some relation?

Yes: file offset *must* be congruent to `VirtAddr` and `PhysAddr` modulo page size, because the file is `mmap`ed directly (by the kernel loader).

If you do not maintain that relationship, the kernel will create a new process, attempt to map your executable into it, discover that you've violated basic constraint, and will terminate your process (with `SIGKILL`, I believe). Your process never executes a single instruction in user-space.

Comment: what does mean "congruent to VirtAddr and PhysAddr modulo page size" please

Answer (score -1):

No stack frame is created then it means there is some problem occurs before entry point. 
Please tell me whether the file is linked with any library modules like libc because they will provide initial setup to call our entry point function.
Use gdb and make breakpoint at _start. If you don't linked with library then the task of setting up stack, arguments, environment will be your responsibility.

Comment: The binary file is not linked with any library, but I do not use any library function calls. I use linux kernel system calls available through interrupts. I am also not using any dynamic linker, I just want pure code execution without any additional environment and it is possible. I just don't understand why it is not possible when I just move address of second segment 20 bytes further.

Comment: Your previous file is working fine ? , data and text addresses are  not page aligned and fall inside same page.

Comment: You called kernel elf loader or any other miscellaneous loader added ?

Comment: This should be no problem. Kernel actually performs alignment itself from what I saw in `fs/binfmt_elf.c`. It just rewrites certain data in first segment by data from second segment. I've just updated my original post with second edit, could you please look at that? It is all weird to me right now.

Comment: If you know the offset of .data just move that to address where .data segment is getting started

Comment: I used regular elf loader in linux kernel. No dynamic linker was used (as you can see by absence of `INTERP` segment)

Comment: Read section header and find start of . Data section in elf file say offset x and then transfer the contents using mmap to virtual address  mmap( vaddr_data, elf-file, x) I didn't mentioned all arguments . So if you data section says that it starts from offset x in elf file which is in disk. So to transfer the contents to memory we need offset and address

Comment: Elf file contains lot of information that is scattered and can be retrieved from headers like in memory where data segment is started and in disk from which file offset data is started. So when we are saying address then if refers to memory and offset is termed with file stored in disk. In your program when you moved data 20 bytes then your library elfio also moved data in file.

Comment: I have one more observation regarding elfio that if you didn't moved file offset then why wrong contents are getting mapped in memory. You just change program header P_vaddr by changing .data virtual address field and it is not necessary to move file contents to different offset; please post this to elfio mailing list